# R Arules Item Frequency Plot Rotate Axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, rotation, arules

I'm doing some pattern mining in R using `library(arules)`. Using `ItemFrequencyPlot` I am trying to rotate the x-axis labels and scale the axis names.

```
library(arules)    
data(Adult)
itemFrequencyPlot(Adult, topN=20, cex.names=0.7, las = 2, srt = 90, main = "Item frequency plot") #example
```

Scaling I can do with `cex.names`. However, when it comes to rotating the axis labels, I'm having a hard time doing so. I have tried both variations of `las` and `srt`. In all, it seems a bit clunky, so perhaps there is another way for visualising it?

***How to rotate the axis labels (and access other graphical elements of the item frequency plot to tweak it)?***

Comment: What is wrong with your current solution?

Comment: The x-axis labels are rotated 45 degrees, I was looking at a solution where the I would rotate the labels 90 degrees. The current does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itemFrequencyPlot` does not appear to allow you to control those labels, but it is after all just a `barplot`, which does give you more control of the appearance. So just make your own. Here is how. Get the top 20 frequencies. Leave *lots* of room for the long axis labels. And plot!

```
iF20 = rev(tail(sort(itemFrequency(Adult)), 20))
par(mar=c(12,4,1,1))
barplot(iF20, las=2, cex.names=0.8)
```

[image: Do-it-yourself itemFrequencyPlot]

Comment: Thank you! That was what I was looking for - great!